# How to change indexer multi-store sequence

Tags: magento2, indexer

I'm working on a Magento2 with 100's of websites in a multi-store setup. We're presently not using the asynchronous indexing feature, but rather re-index in full once per day. The whole reindexing process takes about 1 hour.

It appears that Magento processes each store in sequence by store_id. That means, a store with a high id - e.g. 765 - will not get re-indexed until all the other ones are fully processed. This repeats for each individual indexer.

I would like to affect that sequence so that certain stores - let's say the most active ones - get processed first.

Pretty sure, I'm going to need to write a module for this, but I'm looking for help with where to tap into the execution chain to override the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A quick win for you is to write an after plugin to the function `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::getStores`: in this function, just reorganise the stores with your important stores being sorted first.

I had other ideas but this is by far the least intrusive and most likely fastest to implement.

Comment: Yes, that might be a good first step. Thank you for that suggestion. Would love to hear more ideas if you have the time to share. Easy and quick is not a requirement for me in this case.

Comment: I understand this. I will add details on how I came to this solution. Although it sounds superfluous, I still believe it may well work and be the best solution.